# Embed editable MS Word document on web page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, ms-word

I need to present Word and PDF documents in a *read-only* preview, via an ASPX/HTML page to my internal users.  In a related requirement, I need to present *editable* Word documents, via ab ASPX/HTML page, to parties outside of our network - effectively the public.

We cannot rely upon Word or Adobe-type PDF plugins being available on the destination PC.

Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Edit - For clarity, the document/data would *ideally* stay on our own servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using [Google Docs API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#creating_or_uploading_text_documents)? You could use either their word-like doc or a form to get the data you need, and then present that internally.

Not sure if this meets all of your requirements, or is an available option.

For our company, we have a few tools that utilize Google Docs. We upload data dynamically to them for specific needs.

Based on your requirements, maybe it's best to just write your own. I haven't created a Rich Text Editor. But it looks like there are quite a few tutorials online. Here is a [basic tutorial for a rich text editor](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/246337-a-simple-text-editor-in-html-javascript-and-a-tiny-bit-of-css/). It's using javascript, HTML, & CSS. If you prefer to not use js, then you may need to look for other tutorials.

This isn't the most glamorous solution, as it looks like the users view would be HTML. I'd think you could have it updating dynamically off to the side with an actual rich text view (similar to how Stack Overflow has theirs below an answer or question being written).

**Update**
Over the weekend I was exploring HTML5's `contenteditable` attribute, I came across an editor that builds off of that called **[Aloha Editor](http://www.aloha-editor.org/)**. It's a WYSIWYG type editor. But if that's something that you desire for your clients, than this would probably be a pretty simple integration. I have yet to use it, but it seems like it would be a great fit - if you decide to go the route of building your own editor.

Comment: Hosting data elsewhere, for example with Google Docs, is a none starter unfortunatly.  Equally, we need changes made to the document to be reflected back 'locally' to us.

Comment: Oh right. Need the data to reside on your server. How _fancy_ does the doc editor need to be? Can you just do a basic Text field that they put their content in? Or are you wanting them to be able to have formatting abilities?

Comment: I updated my answer with another possible solution. Probably not the most ideal. But would be a fun project & give you the most control over the long run.

Comment: The Aloha Editor looks like a very viable option, thanks for following up.  Since my OP, there is also the possibility we might get away with the Google Docs API.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Zoho API](https://apihelp.wiki.zoho.com/) or, if you need to keep all data on your own servers and validated clients at all times, you could try the [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/.net/total-component.aspx) components.

Comment: The data does need to stay on our servers.  The Aspose option looks as though it only allows the documents to be rendered and not edited...

Comment: @Danny Yep, you'd have to write your own editing component, or convert to a format which is more easily editable and then convert back afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested to provide documents in a view-only way then you can try GroupDocs as well: http://groupdocs.com/. They offer viewers for different file types which you can add to your website very easily: http://groupdocs.com/apps/viewer.

Comment: This looks a neat solution but unfortunately the PUPM pricing model doesn't work that great for us, nor does the somewhat restricted feature set in terms of document volumes and sizes.  It may be a good solution for others though.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to keep data on your own server, aceoffix can be one of your alternative. It is a plugin installed on your own server and save all data on your server too.