# Adding word control to asp page?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-word

Is it possible to add a Microsoft Office Word control to an aspx page?  I want to be able to modify a load and modify a word document from a web page... I'm just not sure if this is possible?

I know there are AJAX controls out there that allow you to perform something somewhat similar, but I would like to use a Microsoft product if possible.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and VB.NET to try and accomplish this.

Comment: Answer updated, new ideas :)

Answer (score 2):

Use Ms Word vía ActiveX in ASP.NET it's a bad bad idea. It's possible, but currently, this way is not supported by Microsoft, in fact (http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/257757).

You will have troubles with performance, scalabity, user's word versions.... And you will have a lot out-controlled winword.exe processes, and so on.

For this reasons, I use a Silverlight Rich Edit Control, from Devxpress. I had a license already, so I didn't try other solutions, like Telerik's Richtextbox, or Google Docs.

[Embed editable MS Word document on web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283541/embed-editable-ms-word-document-on-web-page)

**Edit**: I remembered that another way it's using WebDav. I mean, force to client MS Word to open a word doc in a WebDav location. Maybe you can consider it.

[How to create a HTML link which forces MS Word to edit document on webdav server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653442/how-to-create-a-html-link-which-forces-ms-word-to-edit-document-on-webdav-server)

This is the addin for IE:

http://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=15123

Answer (score 2):

You can use RadEditor for ASP.NET AJAX in your ASPX pages to import DOCX or RTF files, edit their contents in your browser and save them to DOCX,RFT or PDF format. The following examples show how to do that:

[Import and Export to DOCX](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/import-export/docx-import-export/defaultvb.aspx?show-source=true)

[Import and Export to RTF](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/import-export/rtf-import-export/defaultvb.aspx?show-source=true)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, from the reference i got, it look possible.

Follow this link : [Click Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/404688/Word-Excel-ActiveX-Controls-in-ASP-NET)