# Implementing Microsoft Word onto website or very similar

Tags: ms-word, editor, wysiwyg

I need to implement Microsoft Word into my works website and I'm having real trouble trying to find any information about it. Is there a way to do this? I need mail merge functionality but I don't mind whether it just works with my website (database website)rather than being implemented into it

(I've used CKEditor and TinyMCE but neither are useful for my website/work. I need it to be simple and I'm working with people who just know basic Word)

Comment: I don't think there is a way to run Microsoft Word in a website.  Word needs to be installed on the user's computer / mobile device.

Comment: I just need to know if this is a realistic possibility. I've been told for 6 months by my coding team that we can't but now it's come to crunch time it's all of a sudden do-able

Comment: Who has told you it is do-able?  What is doable?

Comment: It's hard for me to explain but I'll try my best. The people who created my work's bespoke system which we use for data capture, watching orders, sending out 'prizes' as such or sending out cheques. With all the prizes we send letters but it is cheques which is pain staking. We need to be able to lock text in place and use margins but the people using this aren't very computer literate so it MUST be simple. We mail merge customer details on to cheques and letters but it doesn't need to be IN my website, just useable with my systems data e.g. mail merge cutstomer names onto the cheque template

Comment: Based on the info in your last comment my recommendation would be to look at creating the documents using Word Open XML. Probably with a Custom XML Part linked to Content Controls. Or generate PDFs. And just program a "useful" interface for the users - don't worry about showing them the real document/cheque.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can embed (real) Microsoft Word editing functionality in an arbitrary website.

However, if you are running a Sharepoint server, then you can upload MS Word documents to Sharepoint and edit there them via a web browser via "word Web App".  It also allows the user to "one click" download a document and edit it Word installed on their machine.

References:

- Microsoft's [Introduction to Word Web App](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Word-Web-App-a432f1f1-2ea3-454a-9336-26412a20d288)

Alternatively, if you are prepared to look at 3rd-party solutions, some are listed in these Q&As:

- [Embed editable MS Word document on web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283541/embed-editable-ms-word-document-on-web-page)
- [Making Word document embedded in a web page editable or read-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606537/making-word-document-embedded-in-a-web-page-editable-or-read-only)

However, this is dangerously close to asking for a recommendation for software or a web-based service, and that is off-topic.